# Books on chess mathematics

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, chessboard, algorithmic-game-theory

My question is whether there are some books on chess mathematics with theorems and their proofs concerning winning strategies for classes of initial positions. Despite there being a lot of books on chess theory and surveys on the use of AI in chess, it seems there is no purely mathematic chess theory that may use the results of game or group theory. If this is the case, then someone has to start it (despite obvious combinatorial difficulties).

Comment: Have a look at http://www.kotesovec.cz/

Comment: Hi. Great question! Related questions on stackexchange: [Is there a mathematical theorem that you can use to win a chess endgame?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/is-there-a-mathematical-theorem-that-you-can-use-to-win-a-chess-endgame); [Can one make high-level proofs about chess positions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229732/can-one-make-high-level-proofs-about-chess-positions)

Comment: And relevant papers:  [Zermelo and the early history of game theory](https://abel.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/FS23j.03/zermelo.pdf); [A mathematical analysis of the game of chess,
John C. White](https://firescholars.seu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1096&context=honors); [Math and chess, John MacQuarrie](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Projects/MacQuarrie/chapter-4/);

Comment: A big old book: [The grand tactics of chess, Franklin Young](https://www.goodreads.com/search?query=Franklin%20Knowles%20Young%20grand%20tactics); a chess.com forum discussion: [What's the relationship between Chess Theory and the Mathematics of Chess?](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/whats-the-relationship-between-chess-theory-and-the-mathematics-of-chess);

Comment: Also, not really the thing you ask about, but I recommend Raymond Smullyan's "Chess mysteries of Sherlock Holmes", a fun book of problems about chess written by a mathematician. These are problems of the form "Look at this chess position and prove whose turn it is" or "Prove what was the last move played" or "The white and black pieces on this chess position have been repainted in red and green, prove which side has been painted red and which side has been painted green and who played the last move"

Comment: The only kind of solving chess (or at least positions upto $7$ , claimed $8$ pieces) , is backtracking , but this is not really determining structures but exhaustive search. Not even a clearcut-method how to win queen versus rook (without other pieces) has been established. By the way , despite there are some links between math and chess , they are completely different.

Comment: Chess is not yet solved , but if the depressing development of the computers continues it might be solved soon. You "just" have to mark the about $10^{43}$ legal positions in a gigantic database. But as far as I know , noone actually established mathematical algorithms to make it easier to solve it , how this was done in easier games as "four wins".